# Putting a SPPersistedObject on a user

Tags: web-part

I would like to persist some information entered via my web part so the next time the same user uses it, the settings will be pre-populated.

In the Windows world, I would just slap the data is HKCU, but in the brave new world I have no idea what to to.

I have written some code to store values at the SPFarm level,  but I can't seem to figure out the site level.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a button on the web part to save the property? If so, just write the data to a public property on the web part with it's PersonalizationScope set to User. Thus, the property will be stored against the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SPPersistedObject on SPFarm or SPWebApplication level. The PropertyBag can be used on sites via SPWeb.Properties. But I would not store user-specific data in either of these stores. I would go with James' suggestion or put the data in a SQL database...

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint Server you could try using the UserProfile class and creating a custom profile property with your preferences.

Links: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262327.aspx), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx).